# gls model plotting with 95% intervals

Tags: r, plot, syntax, intervals, lm

I am trying to plot my gls predicted values with 95% confidence and I am struggling with the syntax.

I have done this with a gam model previously with the following code:

```
m1 <- gam(Chl ~ s(IR, fx= F, k= -1, bs = "cr"))
m1pred <- predict(m1, se=T, type = "response")

plot(IR, Chl, type ="p")
I1 <- order(IR)
lines(IR[I1], m1pred$fit[I1], lty=1, col="red", lwd = 3 )
lines(IR[I1], m1pred$fit[I1]+2*m1pred$se[I1], lty=2, col = "red", lwd =2)
lines(IR[I1], m1pred$fit[I1]-2*m1pred$se[I1], lty=2, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

but this does not work for a gls model as it says:

Error in pred2$fit : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I have got to this point with an alternate method where i can plot the predicted model and the data following some of Zurr et al (2009) code:

```
plot(IR, Chl,
 ylim = c(0, 2.5), pch= 21,
 ylab = "Chl concentration µg/L", xlab = "Incident irradiance  (W/m-2)")

MyX <- data.frame(IR = seq(from = min(IR),
                       to = max(IR), length = 1076), ID = "IR")
pred2 <- predict(m1s, newdata = MyX)
lines(MyX$IR, pred2, col="red", lwd=3)
```

But I am then not sure how to add the 95% interval lines?

I think I can get the intervals using this syntax from the AICmodav package:

```
predictSE.gls(m1s, MyX, se.fit=T)
lines(MyX$IR, predse, col="red", lwd=1)
```

But then I am not sure how to plot this as it seems the x and y variables are then different...can anyone help?

I am not amazing with R so the simpler the explanation the more I will be able to take away from it.

Thanks in advance
Luci

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a reproducible example, all we can do is guess: Try:

```
plot(IR, Chl, type ="p")
I1 <- order(IR)
lines(IR[I1], m1pred[I1 , 1], lty=1, col="blue", lwd = 3 )
lines(IR[I1], m1pred[I1 , 1]+2*m1pred[I1, "se.fit"], lty=2, col = "red", lwd =2)
lines(IR[I1], m1pred[I1 , 1]-2*m1pred[I1, "se.fit"], lty=2, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

Results of predict may be matrix or vector rather than lists. That's what the error message is trying to get you to recognize. This shouldn't be an error that comes from a predict-object produced by `mgcv::predict.gam` or`gam::predict.gam`, but you didn't include a `library` call, so we don't know which package `gam` comes from. You really should be calling functions with full parameter names (`se.fit` rather than `se`) and using `TRUE` instead of `T`.